# bootstrap modal popup c# codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap in my c# asp.net project and i want to show to show the modal popup from code behind.

in my page header i have a javascript function as follows:

```
function LoginFail() {
        $('#windowTitleDialog').modal('show');
    }
```

and on the click of my button i am calling the javascript as follows

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "LoginFail", "LoginFail();", true);
```

this does not show the modal popup. however, if i use something like `alert('login failed')`, it works fine.

can anybody please help with this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default Bootstrap javascript files are included just before the closing body tag

```
    <script src="vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/easypiechart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts.js"></script>
 </body>
```

I took these javascript files into the head section right before the body tag and I wrote a small function to call the modal popup:

```
<script src="vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/easypiechart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function openModal() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

then I could call the modal popup from code-behind with the following:

```
protected void lbEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {   
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"Pop", "openModal();", true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved:

The Script function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoginFail() {
        $('#windowTitleDialog').modal();
    }        
</script>
```

The Button declaration

```
<asp:Button ID="LaunchModal" runat="server" Text="Launch Modal" CssClass="btn" onclick="LaunchModal_Click"/>
```

*Notice that the attribute data-togle="modal" is not set.*

The Server-side code in the LaunchModal_Click event is:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "LaunchServerSide", "$(function() { LoginFail(); });", true);
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Saved a life mate :) I hope people facing this issue within content pages wrap the method inside document.ready as you have done. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are using one of jQuery modal plugins. In that case, I suspect, plugin code isn't initialized at the time it is called (which would be immediately after it is rendered into page). You have to postpone call to the function after plugin code is executed. Implementation for your case might look like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "LoginFail", "$(function() { LoginFail(); });", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, tried to find online solution but i was unable to do so. I am able to call other javascript funcionts as you said from the code behind but when i add the modal js function the modal does not show up.

My guess is that the modal.('show') function is not being call because when i insepct in crhome the modal element the class is modal hide fade and not modal hide fade IN and other attributes stay the same.

A possible solution is to change those attributes from the code behind, i mean you can do what the js does from the code behind, possible not the best solution but i did not what else to do. By doing this i got the modal to show up with the background grey but could not make the effect to work.

Answer (score 0):

I do this in the aspx page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="MessagePanel" runat="server" CssClass="hide"  EnableViewState="false">
<div class="modal-header">
<asp:Button type="button" ID="btnClose" runat="server" data-dismiss="modal" Text="x" />
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<h4>What's new in this version</h4>
... rest of bootstrap modal stuff....
</div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Then in code-behind to show the modal popup on any event such as page.load or a button click I just change the CssClass of the Panel:

```
MessagePanel.CssClass = "modal fade in"
```

No need for js or ScriptManager.