# Open Modal when access is incorrect - Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, visual-studio-2015

How can I open a Bootstrap Modal when my usuárou or password is incorrect ?

Use the following code

```
 if(Login.logarUsuario(txtUser.Text, txtSenha.Text))

        {
            //Cria um cookie do lado do servidor
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("estado", "conectado");

            //Define a validade do cookie (10 dias a partir de hoje)
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12);

            //Envia o cookie para o cliente
            Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

            //Redireciona para a pagina inicial
            Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            //MODAL OPEN HERE
        }
```

Comment: This should assist you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688572/bootstrap-modal-popup-c-sharp-codebehind

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tested the code did not work .. still not showing the modal when it authenticates the user